# How to calculate a bounded permutation repeated game

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

Suppose I want to solve the following problem:

I have $n$ balls labeled $i=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, and I choose $k$ balls out of the bag. I then remove the highest of the $k$ balls, but only if its value is above $b$. Otherwise, I return all the balls back into the bag. I play this game $j$ times. What is the probability for all balls $>b$ that they remain in the bag after $j$ plays?

EDIT TO ANSWER QUESTION:
So so far I have gotten through the following:

In the first round, each ball has "i-1 choose k" over "n choose k" chance of being the highest.

Thus, the chance to remain for the first round is: p(remain) = 1 - 1{i > b*("i-1 choose k" / "n choose k"), as they also have to be above the b bound.

If this was all that had to be done iterating on this it'd be fine. The problem is trying to wrap my mind around how this evolves as the other balls above and below the value have a hazard of leaving the bag.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you facing problems ?Pl edit your efforts into the body of the question.

Comment: Alright I edited my current progress.

Comment: please improve the question by using tex and also write a complete question at once not in two parts.